# cordova can't build the project with phonegap parse plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, parse-platform, phonegap-build

Cordova can't build the project with [this](https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin) plugin.

When I import the project in eclipse, eclipse shows error in `ParsePlugin.java`

```
private void initialize(final CallbackContext callbackContext, final JSONArray args) {
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(cordova.getActivity(), cordova.getActivity().getClass());
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        callbackContext.success();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error that Eclipse shows?

Comment: you can see screenshot of error in this photo : https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1368996/7748113/ebada928-ffd6-11e4-975e-73525ff42794.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue fixed by  bolts-android.XXX.jar from Parse.zip
and copy it to platform/android/lib/